# Brew Formula: How can I define cask and external dependencies?

Tags: osx, package-management, dependencies, homebrew, brew

I’m writing a [brew formula](https://github.com/kenokenobingo/homebrew-memetap) for my own tap, having XQuartz and external sources (not available on brew) as dependencies. How can I include them in my formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Cask, if you need X11, you should add:

```
depends_on x11: true
```

if you need java 7 or higer:

```
depends_on_java '7+'
```

if you need exactly java 8:

```
depends_on_java '8'
```

if you need the formula nmap:

```
depends_on formula: 'nmap'
```

if you need the cask virtualbox:

```
depends_on cask: 'virtualbox'
```

if you need a minimum macOS version:

```
depends_on macos: '>= :mavericks'
```

if you need something that is nor a formula nor a cask add a formula or a cask for it.